# IllegalArgumentException while using ReactiveCouchbaseRepository Expected to find reactive adapter for class rxSingle but couldnt

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, couchbase, spring-webflux

I'm working on a [reactive](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) application that uses [Springboot WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html) framework and Couchbase DB.
Spring provides the JPA implementation for Couchbase and my repository interface looks like this.

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Example, String> {

}
```

And I enable reactive Couchbase repositories in the Spring config (Java based) file this way

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = { "com.examples.repository" })
public class CouchDatabaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
```

When I try to retrieve data from DB by invoking findById() method of the repository, I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected to find reactive adapter for class rx.Single but couldn't!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have spent a lot of time to figure out why this exception is coming, as no other Google search result helped me out. I'm posting the solution here hoping it will be helpful for someone like me.

**Reason**

> **Either you have not included the dependency for reactive streams or you have included an incompatible one.**

Adding this line to my build.gradle saved my life.

```
compile('io.reactivex:rxjava-reactive-streams')
```